# Can you be prosecuted for doing something legal abroad (but that is considered illegal in your home country)?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, jurisdiction

Let's say you are a U.S. citizen and you go to Country X for vacation (or more specifically, with the intent to commit that crime abroad - in case that makes any difference).

In Country X, it is legal to murder people and consume illicit drugs, so you do that before coming home.

Did you commit any crime at all? Has anyone ever been prosecuted for something similar?

Comment: In the abstract, yes, but typically it is limited to serious crimes that are explicitly established with extraterritorial effect.  Consumption of controlled substances typically isn't among these; murder can be, depending on the circumstances, but usually isn't.

Comment: @phoog Thanks for the note!